# MongoDB regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, replace, mongodb-query

My table name is : table_video
My field name in db is : url_value

Whose value is : http://192.168.1.124/test/**abcd**/**abcd**.m3u8

Value which is needed by me : http://192.168.1.124/test/**abcd_NEW**/**abcd_NEW**.m3u8

There are multiple values in place of "abcd", above url is just one example.

```
var cursor = db.table_video.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var x = cursor.next();
  print("\n\n-----------------------------------");

  print("Before : url_value : "+x['url_value']);

  x['url_value'] = x['url_value'].replace(/^(.*?)\/test\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\.m3u8$/g, $1/test/$2_NEW/$2_NEW.m3u8);

  print("After : url_value : "+x['url_value']);

  db.table_video.update({_id : x._id}, x);

}
```

When I execute above command in mongo console, it gives an error : 2015-11-28T12:40:08.342+0530 ReferenceError: $1 is not defined

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: [Check This](https://regex101.com/r/nU7kM2/1)

Comment: My regex is already working in Kate, even I checked the link you provided, however it's giving error in mongodb

Comment: @user2767817 your regex is wrong it will not work in Mongo. use the one provided by Uchiha.

Comment: Regex provided by Uchiha is right, however, when I use in mongodb, it gives error : 2015-11-28T12:40:08.342+0530 ReferenceError: $1 is not defined

Comment: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33968553/edit) your question to include the new code

Comment: Sure, will edit the same

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is wrong you can get the expected result using this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/nU7kM2/1)<sup>1</sup>.

But the best way to do this is using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations for maximum efficiency.

```
var bulk = db.table_video.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.table_video.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var newUrlValue = doc.url_value.replace(/^(.*?)\/test\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\.m3u8$/, '$1/test/$2_NEW/$3_NEW.m3u8');
    bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( { 
        '$set': { 'url_value': newUrlValue } 
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 100 === 0) {
        // Execute per 100 operation and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.table_video.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        count = 0;
    }
})

// Clean up queues
if (count > 0)  bulk.execute();
```

---

If your MongoDB version is older that 2.6 you need to use a while loop.

```
var cursor = db.table_video.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var x = cursor.next();
    print("\n\n-----------------------------------");
    print("Before : url_value : "+x['url_value']);
    var newUrlValue = x['url_value'].replace(/^(.*?)\/test\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\.m3u8$/, '$1/test/$2_NEW/$2_NEW.m3u8');
    print("After : url_value : "+newUrlValue);
    db.table_video.update({ _id : x._id }, { '$set': { 'url_value': newUrlValue } } );

}
```

---

1. Regex provided by @Uchiha.

Comment: Hi @zypA13510, thanks for pointing this out. Feel free to edit the answer. I will approve it. Use your comment as edit summary.

Comment: @zypA13510 I overwrote the decision

Answer (score 1):

in mongodb version 4.2 you have [regexFind project operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/) which can be used to get the matches, then you ocan use [substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) to replace parts of the pattern